# Using PyQt5 table, make text visible in padded cell with background color and change background color on condition

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to display a grid of colored squares that display data inside, and the color of the squares to change color depending on value of the data inside it.  Right now I have a grid of blue squares that when I click on it, it does print the value correctly but I cannot see the value inside the squares and the color doesn't change.  Can someone please look at my code and tell me where I have gone wrong?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QStyledItemDelegate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TableDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, padding):
        super().__init__()
        self.padding = padding

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        adjusted_padding = self.padding // 2  # Reduce the padding by half
        option.rect.adjust(adjusted_padding, adjusted_padding, -adjusted_padding, -adjusted_padding)
        painter.fillRect(option.rect, QColor('blue'))

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.backgroundBrush = QColor('blue')  # Set cell background color to blue
        option.displayAlignment = (Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)  # Center align text

class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, padding):
        super().__init__(len(data), len(data[0]))
        self.init_ui(data, padding)

    def init_ui(self, data, padding):
        self.setShowGrid(False)  # Hide grid lines
        self.setItemDelegate(TableDelegate(padding))

        cell_padding = padding * 3  # Triple the padding

        for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(data):
            for col_idx, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(str(col_data) if col_data is not None else '')  # Convert None to empty string
                self.setItem(row_idx, col_idx, item)
                self.setRowHeight(row_idx, cell_padding)  # Set triple row height
                self.setColumnWidth(col_idx, cell_padding)  # Set triple column width

                # Set text color to contrast with blue background
                if isinstance(col_data, float) and col_data < 2.0:
                    item.setForeground(QColor('pink'))  # Set color to pink
                else:
                    item.setForeground(QColor('white'))  # Set color to white

                # Set text alignment to the center
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                # Ensure text is visible within cells
                if col_data is not None:
                    self.item(row_idx, col_idx).setText(str(col_data))

        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)  # Hide vertical headers (row numbers)
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)  # Hide horizontal headers (column headings)
        self.cellClicked.connect(self.print_clicked_value)  # Connect cellClicked signal to method

    def print_clicked_value(self, row, col):
        item = self.item(row, col)
        if item is not None:
            print(item.text())  # Print value of the clicked cell

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    padding = 20  

    data = [
        [1.2, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.1, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [3, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.01, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [2.1, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.1, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.04, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.89, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.4, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
    ]

    table = TableWidget(data, padding)
    table.setWindowTitle('Table Widget')
    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
,,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `paint()` preventing the default behavior to properly show the content of the cell, because what you do there is just drawing the rectangle.

Instead, you should call the base implementation using the updated option rectangle:

```py
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        adjusted_padding = self.padding // 2
        option.rect.adjust(adjusted_padding, adjusted_padding, -adjusted_padding, -adjusted_padding)
        super().paint(painter, option, index)
```

Note that a delegate should always be created with a parent, which normally is the item view itself. While it normally works even without the parent, doing it is discouraged, and will create issues in case you want to use different delegates on the same view.

```py
class TableDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, padding, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.padding = padding


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    ...
    def init_ui(self, data, padding):
        self.setShowGrid(False)  # Hide grid lines
        self.setItemDelegate(TableDelegate(padding, self))
        ...
```

Finally, since you will probably want to check the numeric value in order to change the background, you should store it as a value, other than the string. For this you can use a custom role, and test it in the delegate:

```
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        value = index.data(Qt.UserRole)
        if isinstance(value, (float, int)) and value > 2:
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor('green')
        else:
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor('blue')
        option.displayAlignment = (Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
                ...
                item.setData(Qt.UserRole, col_data)
```

Comment: That's fantastic musicamante and very well explained cheers :)

Comment: 1 more question please musicamante, could you tell me how to prevent the cells highlight on hover and clicked?  I found your previous answer from over a year ago and applied it, but the cell turned transparent with dotted line around the squares after click-self.setStyleSheet(
            "QTableWidget { selection-color: palette(text); selection-background-color: palette(base); }"
        )

Comment: If you don't want *absolutely any* hint about hover or selection, then you could add `option.state &= ~(QStyle.State_Selected|QStyle.State_MouseOver)` at the end of `def initStyleOption()`.

Comment: works perfectly thanks musicamante