# PyQt5 multi-lines in cell

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is related to ([Using PyQt5 table, make text visible in padded cell with background color and change background color on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77603216/using-pyqt5-table-make-text-visible-in-padded-cell-with-background-color-and-ch)) in which I was wondering if I have 2 values for a cell, is it possible to have the second value on a new line in the same cell (but have all the conditions (background colour etc) based on the first value in each cell?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QStyledItemDelegate,QStyle
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class TableDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, padding, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.padding = padding

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        adjusted_padding = self.padding // 2
        option.rect.adjust(adjusted_padding, adjusted_padding, -adjusted_padding, -adjusted_padding)
        super().paint(painter, option, index)

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        value = index.data(Qt.UserRole)
        if value is None:
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor(Qt.transparent)  # Set cell transparent if value is None
        elif index.column() == 4:  # Check if the column index is 4 (fifth column)
            if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                if value > 2:
                    option.backgroundBrush = QColor(
                        'green')  # Set background color to green based on value in the fifth column
                elif value < 0:
                    option.backgroundBrush = QColor(
                        'red')  # Set background color to red for negative values in the fifth column
                else:
                    option.backgroundBrush = QColor(
                        'blue')  # Set background color to blue for other cases in the fifth column
        elif index.column() == 1:  # Check if the column index is 1 (second column)
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor(
                'red')  # Set background color to red for non-None values in the second column
        else:
            option.backgroundBrush = QColor('blue')  # For other columns, set the background color to blue

        option.displayAlignment = (Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        option.state &= ~(QStyle.State_Selected | QStyle.State_MouseOver)


class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, padding):
        super().__init__(len(data), len(data[0]))
        self.init_ui(data, padding)

    def init_ui(self, data, padding):
        self.setShowGrid(False)
        self.setItemDelegate(TableDelegate(padding, self))
        cell_padding = padding * 3

        for row_idx, row_data in enumerate(data):
            for col_idx, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
                has_column_9 = len(row_data) > 8#marketId and Selection Id
                if col_data is not None:
                    item = QTableWidgetItem(str(col_data))
                    self.setItem(row_idx, col_idx, item)
                    self.setRowHeight(row_idx, cell_padding)
                    self.setColumnWidth(col_idx, cell_padding)

                    if isinstance(col_data, float) and col_data < 2.0:
                        item.setForeground(QColor('pink'))
                    else:
                        item.setForeground(QColor('white'))

                    item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                    self.item(row_idx, col_idx).setText(str(col_data))

                    if col_idx == 0:
                        self.setColumnWidth(col_idx, cell_padding * 2)
                    else:
                        self.setColumnWidth(col_idx, cell_padding)

                    item.setData(Qt.UserRole, col_data)
                    # Hide the entire row if column 9 exists
                    if has_column_9:
                        self.setRowHidden(row_idx, True)
                else:
                    item = QTableWidgetItem('')
                    item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
                    item.setBackground(QColor(Qt.transparent))
                    item.setForeground(QColor(Qt.transparent))
                    self.setItem(row_idx, col_idx, item)
                    self.setColumnWidth(col_idx, 0)
                    self.setRowHeight(row_idx, 0)

        self.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.cellClicked.connect(self.print_clicked_value)


    def print_clicked_value(self, row, col):
        item = self.item(row, col)
        if item is not None:
            print(item.text())

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    padding = 20

    data = [
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None,None],
        [1.2, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, None,4.0],
        [1.1, 1.02, None, 1.16, None,3],
        [3, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.01, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, None,None,0,8,9999999],
        [2.1, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 6,None,None,0],
        [1.1, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.04, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.89, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0],
        [1.4, 1.02, 1.1, 1.16, 670.0,4,6,7]
    ]

    table = TableWidget(data, padding)
    table.setWindowTitle('Table Widget')
    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example of data:

```
data = [[(1.5, 2), (1.4, 2.0), (1.1, 1.5)],
     [(2.0, 3), (2.5, 1.8), (3.0, None)],
     [(0.5), (None), (1.2, 1.7)],
     [(3.5, 4), (None), (4.1, 3.9)],
     [(4.5, 5), (4.7, 5.1), (5.01)]]
```

Comment: The concept is exactly the same as explained at the end of my answer: check the `index.data(Qt.UserRole)`; in this case, if it's a tuple or list, then check the *first* value. Note that calling `self.item().setText()` is pointless, as you already set the text when you created the QTableWidgetItem.